# ES search query call and return only selected fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to write a query for Elastic Search that would return the first 20 closest matches.

I want to return the first 20 matches for the title field.

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/xxx/_search?pretty=true" -d '
{
"from" : 0,
"size" : 20,
"query" : { "term" : {"title" : "art"} }}'
```

What am I missing here?

Update:

I'm trying to get only the 'title' field returned, not the whole object.

Comment: ES automatically returns results odered by score.

Comment: The query looks good, default sorting is by score. What is exactly the   problem?

Comment: Ahh I just saw that I had a missing curly brace but! The problem is I'm trying to get only the Title returned to me. not the whole object.

Comment: I see! ok, nice that you've found the solution in the meantime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this by doing a search with fields param:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/xxx/_search?pretty=true" -d '
{
"from" : 0,
"size" : 20,
"fields" : ["title"],
"query" : { "term" : {"title" : "art"} }}'
```