# Set Custom Payload in wso2 ESB or AM?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a rest API in ESB server.I need to set payload as follows

```
<fields>Name</fields>
<query>
<term>
    <NUM>100</NUM>
</term>
</query>
```

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [payload/enrich](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator) mediators ..

Comment: <query>
<term>
    <NUM>100</NUM>
</term>
</query>    This part automatically removing by ESB

Comment: How is your synapse configuration looks like? If the configuration is wrong, ESB will automatically remove the wrong configuration.

Comment: <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
  <format>
   <fields>Name</fields>
   <query>
    <term>
     <VAL>$1</VAL>
    </term>
   </query>
              
       </format>
       <args>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$url:name"></arg>
       </args>
    </payloadFactory>

Comment: The issue is , your xml is not valid xml. You can try http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp tool to validate the xml which you are giving in the format tag.(that is: <fields>Name</fields><query> <term> <VAL>$1</VAL> </term> </query> ) It is not valid because, it does not have a root element.

Comment: i want to set such like payload.this is the body i want to sent to elastic search server.It should be same format to work its rest end point.

Comment: You can not pass invalid xml:) Waht you can do is, wrap the whole message with another dummy xml tag and pass. Eg:<dummyroot><fields>Name</fields><query> <term> <VAL>$1</VAL> </term> </query></dummyroot>, BTW how your backend server expects an invalid xml?

Comment: Thank u so much for your valuable comments.please go through this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078400/es-search-query-call-and-return-only-selected-fields...I want to set such payload using API manager or ESB .

Answer (score 1):

you could use the payloadfactory  mediator in ESB 4.8.1, take this xml as an example. you need to do some changes :-) but it´s an start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="JsonToXMLProxy"
       transports="https http local"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx" format="soap11"/>
      </endpoint>
      <inSequence>
         <log>
            <property name="TEMPERATURA_ENTRADA" expression="json-eval($.celsius)"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <web:CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns:web="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">
                  <web:Celsius>$1</web:Celsius>
               </web:CelsiusToFahrenheit>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.celsius"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <header name="Action"
                 value="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log>
            <property xmlns:p="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/"
                      name="TEMPERATURA_SALIDA"
                      expression="//p:CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse/p:CelsiusToFahrenheitResult"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
                            "Temperatura" : {
                                "EnFahrenheit" : $1
                            }
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg xmlns:p="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/"
                    evaluator="xml"
                    expression="//p:CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse/p:CelsiusToFahrenheitResult"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```